"can not open source file" but compiles without a problem
So in editor it shows as an error for every standard library module, but when I compile it, it works without a problem. The only annoying thing with this is that because of this the autocomplition doesn't work.
(https://i.sstatic.net/1exjFh3L.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/8SkoU0TK.png)
Yesterday when I created the project everything was fine, but today after I opened it to continue working it gives me theese to message.
Tried using namespace, nothing.

The issue might stem from a problem with the project build. You could try right-clicking on the project within the Solution Explorer, choose "Unload Project", and then right-click again and select "Reload Project with Dependencies".
